# How to import a compiled DLL file with nuget references in Unity?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

What is the proper way of importing a compiled dll file that has nuget references? Do I have to also import the dll of all the nuget references? All all the dlls that those reference? This is what I am currently doing and am going crazy.

Comment: DLLs have no mechanism of referencing NuGet packages. Only other DLLs.